# How do you focus only on a rectangle and read text inside of the rectangle in android camera x

Tags: java, android, android-camerax

Hello I'm developing an android application for scan printed text and get out put as a editable text. So I use android Camera x for these requirement

Here I scan the image and get the output as many requirements(as an editable text).
but in here read full camera view and convert to all viewing text block.
I need to fixed these scanning area (put rectangle and scan only this rectangle area text)

I draw rectangle in camera preview. but TextRecognizer method cannot pass bitmap image data. It can pass only the input image data.

This may be image analyzer and text recognition part

```
  ImageAnalysis imageAnalysis =
            new ImageAnalysis.Builder()
                    .setTargetResolution(new Size(720, 1488))
                    .setBackpressureStrategy(ImageAnalysis.STRATEGY_KEEP_ONLY_LATEST)
                    .build();



    imageAnalysis.setAnalyzer(executor, new ImageAnalysis.Analyzer() {
        @SuppressLint("UnsafeOptInUsageError")
        @Override
        public void analyze(@NonNull ImageProxy imageProxy) {
            mediaImage = imageProxy.getImage();
            assert mediaImage != null;
            InputImage image =InputImage.fromMediaImage(mediaImage, imageProxy.getImageInfo().getRotationDegrees());

            TextRecognizer recognizer = TextRecognition.getClient(TextRecognizerOptions.DEFAULT_OPTIONS);
            Task<Text> result =
                    recognizer.process(image)
                            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Text>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(Text visionText) {
                                     for (Text.TextBlock block : visionText.getTextBlocks()) {
                                         Rect boundingBox = block.getBoundingBox();
                                         Point[] cornerPoints = block.getCornerPoints();
                                         String text = block.getText();

                                         Log.e("get Text", text);

                                         for (Text.Line line : block.getLines()) {
                                             // ...
                                             for (Text.Element element : line.getElements()) {
                                                 // ...
                                             }
                                         }
                                     }
                                }
                            })
                            .addOnFailureListener(
                                    new OnFailureListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                            Log.e("text eger",e.getMessage());
                                        }
                                    }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Text>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Text> task) {
                                    Log.e("text eg", task.getResult().getText());
                                    mediaImage.close();
                                }
                            });
        }
    });
    camera = cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle((LifecycleOwner)this,cameraSelector,preview,imageAnalysis);
}
```